# New default Gradle project in Eclipse - String cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I just run the New Gradle project guide in Eclipse. Oddly enough it just created a `Library.java` and `LibraryTest.java` - no `MyProject.java` with a `main`-class. And even the Library.java skeleton class has a compile error¹.

This raises several questions.

1. Below is an image of the layout of the simplest possible² Gradle project in Eclipse. Is all this really necessary for a simple command line application?

[image: Layout of default Gradle project in Eclipse]

2. And yet (c.f. point 1) no class with a `main`-method is created. Why? (I assume that is expected)
3. And finally, and most importantly, when I create a basic class with a `main`-method, `string` doesn't resolve. What's missing and is there some reason Eclipse/the New Gradle project doesn't set this up automatically?

I have found several questions here on SO with similar problem, e.g., [String cannot be resolved to a type - Java RAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651768/string-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-java-rad) , but their solutions don't apply to my situation.

¹ `Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor`
² The highlighted class is added by me, **everything** else was created by the New Gradle project guide.

Comment: The red exclamation mark tells that your project is wrong configured. The problems message can be found in the _Problems_ view. I guess, it's something with the missing Java system library. What's the exact error message, what do you have in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ and which Java version is required by your project?

Comment: @howlger I added a JRE following the description here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19570719/1802826 and the problem disappeared. I am surprised that this is set to a sensible default value when following a guide like this.

Comment: This is not how you should do it. At least not for a Gradle project. Don't be surprised when following random Stack Overflow answers. Instead, please tell the information I asked for.